# Error in LINQ query when referecing value in combo box

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, linq, combobox

I'm having some trouble making my combo boxes cascade correctly. I'm using WinForms with Entity Framework Code First and I'm struggling to get the second combo box to work correctly. My categories model looks like this:

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

My subcategories looks like this:

```
public class SubCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

In the SelectedIndexChanged event of the category combo box I have tried this code:

```
cmboSubCategory.DataSource = ( from sc in db.SubCategories.AsEnumerable()
                                where sc.Category == int.Parse( cmboCategory.SelectedValue.ToString() )
                                select sc ).ToList();
```

but the compiler tells me

```
Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Category' and 'int'
```

Looking in the database the FK field in the SubCategories table is named Category_ID but when I try to use this field name the compiler complains that the field doesn't exist. How do I lookup using virtual field names as defined in my models? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to equal a Category object with an int. Use id to check if is equal to.

I think you are missing `.ID`

`where sc.Category.ID == int.Parse( cmboCategory.SelectedValue.ToString() )`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to check equality of a Category object to an int. Use id to check if they are equal.

Add the ID property to sc.Category

```
cmboSubCategory.DataSource = ( from sc in db.SubCategories.AsEnumerable()
                            where sc.Category.ID == int.Parse( cmboCategory.SelectedValue.ToString() )
                            select sc ).ToList();
```